# Batch Programming: read txt and keep variables with a subroutine

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a bactch-file for the first time and I have a problem that I couldn't solve yet. (I'm not a programmer but just a mechanical engineer, so please forgive me for my clumsiness.. And my english: I'm not a native speaker...)

I want to write a batch file (*readlist.bat*) that amongst other things should read in a txt-file (*Text.txt*). This batch-file then should be able to be called in another batch file with *"call readlist.bat"*.
What is clear to me is the following: I have to define variables within the *readlist.bat* not only locally if I want them to be stored after *readlist.bat* finishes. I tried to realize this in the attached files at least for some of the variables. (Of course the final goal is to keep all the variables read in from the txt-file.)
But I cant manage this.

The Text.txt only contains "test variables"
*readlist.btat* should read in all rows in columns (this works). But the variables need to be defined "not locally". Therefore for testing reasons I added the following commands:

```
endlocal  
set "job1fld=%job1fld%"  
set "job1dat=%job1dat%"  
set "job1kyw=%job1kyw%"  
set "job2fld=%job2fld%"  
set "job2dat=%job2dat%"  
set "job2kyw=%job2kyw%"  
set "job3fld=%job3fld%"  
set "job3dat=%job3dat%"  
set "job3kyw=%job3kyw%"  

set vartest1=test1  
set vartest2=test2  
set vartest3=test3  
set vartest4=test4  
set vartest5=test5  
set vartest5=test6  
set vartest6=test7
```

the second block seems to work. Or lets say: Those variables are handed over to the *callreadlist*. But those are only manually set test-variables...

The first block however doesn't work and I can't figureout why...

How do I manage that all the variables read in are kept after *readlist.bat* finishes? Because I am an absolute greenhorn when it comes to batch-files, I would be glad if you don't only give me tipps but codes ;-)

Thank you in advance.

Roy

CALLREADLIST.BAT:

```
@echo off
call readlist.bat
set
pause
```

READLIST.BAT:

```
REM =================================
REM =================================
REM READ TXT
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM START: Read 1. Column (Ordner)
set ColNo=1
set cntr1=0
for /F "delims=; tokens=%ColNo%" %%A in (Text.txt) do (
    set /a cntr1=!cntr1! + 1
    set job!cntr1!fld=%%A
)
REM END: Read 1. Column (Ordner)
REM START: Read 2. Column (Ordner)
set ColNo=2
set cntr2=0
for /F "delims=; tokens=%ColNo%" %%A in (Text.txt) do (
    SET /A cntr2=!cntr2! + 1
    set job!cntr2!dat=%%A
)
REM END: Read 2. Column (Ordner)
REM START: Read 3. Column (Ordner)
set ColNo=3
set cntr3=0
for /F "delims=; tokens=%ColNo%" %%A in (Text.txt) do (
    SET /A cntr3=!cntr3! + 1
    set job!cntr3!kyw=%%A
)
REM END: Read 3. Column (Ordner)
endlocal
set "job1fld=%job1fld%"
set "job1dat=%job1dat%"
set "job1kyw=%job1kyw%"
set "job2fld=%job2fld%"
set "job2dat=%job2dat%"
set "job2kyw=%job2kyw%"
set "job3fld=%job3fld%"
set "job3dat=%job3dat%"
set "job3kyw=%job3kyw%"
set vartest1=test1
set vartest2=test2
set vartest3=test3
set vartest4=test4
set vartest5=test5
set vartest5=test6
set vartest6=test7
```

TXT-FILE:

```
Ordner1;Job1;Input1
Ordner2;Job2;Input2
Ordner3;Job3;Input3
Ordner4;Job4;Input4
Ordner5;Job5;Input5
Ordner6;Job6;Input6
Ordner7;Job7;Input7
Ordner8;Job8;Input8
Ordner9;Job9;Input9
Ordner10;Job10;Input10
Ordner11;Job11;Input11
Ordner12;Job12;Input12
Ordner13;Job13;Input13
Ordner14;Job14;Input14
Ordner15;Job15;Input15
Ordner16;Job16;Input16
Ordner17;Job17;Input17
Ordner18;Job18;Input18
Ordner19;Job19;Input19
Ordner20;Job20;Input20
Ordner21;Job21;Input21
Ordner22;Job22;Input22
Ordner23;Job23;Input23
Ordner24;Job24;Input24
Ordner25;Job25;Input25
Ordner26;Job26;Input26
Ordner27;Job27;Input27
Ordner28;Job28;Input28
Ordner29;Job29;Input29
Ordner30;Job30;Input30
Ordner31;Job31;Input31
Ordner32;Job32;Input32
Ordner33;Job33;Input33
Ordner34;Job34;Input34
Ordner35;Job35;Input35
Ordner36;Job36;Input36
Ordner37;Job37;Input37
Ordner38;Job38;Input38
Ordner39;Job39;Input39
```

Comment: your problem is the `endlocal`. this reverts any changes to the variables since `setlocal`. Get rid of `setlocal` and `endlocal` in your readlist.bat. Put them into your callreadlist.bat instead.

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much! Problem solved I would say.
But I have to say: looks quite unlogical to me... I mean the setlocal is then stilled turned on, just even one skript earlier...

Comment: not that unlogical: a daughter-process is running in the environment of the mother-process - so both share the same variables. Unless you tell the daughter explicit to use an own environment with `setlocal`

Answer (score 3):

nice stuff:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('^< Text.txt find /c /v ""') do set /a lines=%%a
<Text.txt (
for /l %%a in (1 1 %lines%) do (
    set "line="
    set /p "line="
    for /f "tokens=1-3delims=;" %%d in ('call echo %%line%%') do (
        set "job%%afld=%%d"&set "job%%asat=%%e"&set "job%%akyw=%%f"
    )
))
set "line="&set "lines="
set "job"
```

This is easy, the real challenge is to give each job-variable a unique number (here 1-117) without `delayed expansion`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
...
REM END: Read 3. Column (Ordner)
endlocal&(
set "job1fld=%job1fld%"
set "job1dat=%job1dat%"
set "job1kyw=%job1kyw%"
set "job2fld=%job2fld%"
set "job2dat=%job2dat%"
set "job2kyw=%job2kyw%"
set "job3fld=%job3fld%"
set "job3dat=%job3dat%"
set "job3kyw=%job3kyw%"
set vartest1=test1
set vartest2=test2
set vartest3=test3
set vartest4=test4
set vartest5=test5
set vartest5=test6
set vartest6=test7
)
```

Essentially, what *should* happen is that the entire last line is parsed from the `ENDLOCAL` through to the closing parenthesis. It is **THEN** executed, but with the `%var%`s replaced by their values at the time the `endlocal&(etc)` was encountered. & allows multiple commands on one physical line...

Answer (score 0):

You want to read each of the columns in Text.txt and store it in variables, right?

Easily:

```
@echo off
set i=1
for /f "delims= ; tokens=1-3" %%a in (Text.txt) do (
    set ordner%i%=%%a
    set job%i%=%%b
    set input%i%=%%c
    set /a i=i+1
)
```

This code will set variables like this:

```
set ordner1=Ordner1
set job1=Job1
set input1=Input1

set ordner2=Ordner2
set job2=Job2
set input2=Input2

...
```

From your calling file (CALLREADLIST.BAT) you can access any column on any line by simply using `%columnLine%` (e.g: `%job26%` where "job" is your column and "26" the line number).

For instance, if you want CALLREADLIST.BAT to output the "Input" at line 45 all you'd need would be:

```
@echo off
readlist
echo %input45%
```

The first block is not working just because you're assigning to variable names their own values, which is null (`set var=%var%`, i.e. `set var=` which undefines the variable).

Comment: Please don't use spaces around `=` with the `set`command. `set ordner%i% = %%a` sets a variable with name (for example) "`ornder1 `" to a value "` Ordner1`". Use `set ordner%i%=%%a` or to be sure that there are no spaces at the end `set "ordner%i%=%%a"`

Comment: Stephan: you're perfectly right. I know that but I get it wrong all the time. I hate this thing. Fixed.

Comment: this doesn't work. Do you  know  why not? You can't access your counter `%i%` inside a code block.

Comment: I can access the counter inside the block by using `!i!` instead of `%i%`.
Noize, your solution seems pretty neat to me, I just think you forgot a `/a` in `set i=1`. But if I do it in three for-loops, I can compare the 4 different counters later on, in order to check if some lines were faulty...

Comment: Actually the `/a` argument is needed only when performing arithmetical operations. It won't give an error if I add it, but it's not needed. "But if I do it in three for-loops, I can compare the 4 different counters later on, in order to check if some lines were faulty..." - I can't get what you mean here.

Comment: Ok strange, %i% didn't work for me

With "But if I do it in three for-loops, I can compare the 4 different counters later on..."
I wanted to say thefollowing:

If not all the lines of the txt contain 4 columns, then the variables get mixed up. Because if there arent four columns in one line it will just take the value from the next line. Therefore if I have four separate loops, I can check if all the counters reached the same number. If they don't, at least one of the lines hasn't got 4 columns in it.

I hope this one was more understandable. Sorry, but my english skills may not be the best...

Comment: If you want to use it for such a purpose as well, and you're sure all your columns will always be `column;column` and never, for instance `col umn; column ;column` then you should replace `delims= ;` with `delims=;` in my code.

Comment: I have already done this :-) But the problem with missing entries in the txt-file remains... If my txt from above is lets say missing the entry "Input2", then "Input3" will be assigned to the variable 'job2kyw'... That's why I probaly will stick to three loops with individual couters which I can compare after reading in all the variables.